# Searching for a string in a text file using Java

Tags: java, text

I am trying to make the user input an Airport Name, and the program will search from a text file to get the matching Code, right now I only need it to read the line. I have looked into many similar questions in here, but nothing works for me. The program return the else result rather than the found result.

This is my code so far

```
 public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
 {
  File file = new File("codes01.dat");
  Scanner myFile = new Scanner(file);

  Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

  String line;
  System.out.println("Hey man, this is totally leigt, just enter an Airport code and I'll hook you up.");
  System.out.print("First, y'all need to give me the file name: ");
  String fileName = kb.nextLine();


  if (fileName.equalsIgnoreCase("codes01"))
  {

     System.out.print("Cool, now give me your Airport Name: ");
     String AirportName = kb.nextLine();
   while (myFile.hasNextLine())
    {
     line = myFile.nextLine();
     String name = myFile.next();
     System.out.println(line);
     if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(AirportName))
     {

     System.out.println("IT'S WORKING, I DON'T KNOW HOW BUT IT IS "+line);
     break;
     }

     else
     {
     System.out.println("Sorry, dude, ain't no airport in my VERY limited list with that name");
     break;
     }
   }

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The program return the else result rather than the found result.

That is because you are breaking out of the loop after testing the first line in your file.

Look carefully at your code ... in context.

```
 if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(AirportName)) {
     System.out.println("It is working");
     break;
 } else {
     System.out.println("Sorry");
     break;   // What????
 }
```

Comment: Hi thank you for such a quick response!

I did get rid of the breaks, it works but to some extent, only the first word works, when I enter any other words in the line, i get 
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
        at AirportCodes1.main(AirportCodes1.java:37)

Comment: And have you tried to solve that problem for yourself?  Did you read the javadocs for the method?  For the exception?  Did you try to figure out why the exception was thrown.  These are things that you need to learn to do for yourself.

Comment: I did research it, mate, I wouldn't just ask you to do my work for me, that's unfair. I know that the compiler is doing this because it's the messed up Next Line and the next commands, I tried solving it by moving them around, but it's still giving me a headache :/ I read JavaDocs, other Stack posts, I still face the same issue.

Note: My file contains a line of text (e.g BOM, Mumbai Airport)
When I type BOM, (with the comma) it works fine, but when I type anything else, it doesn't

Again, thank you so much for your time.

Comment: Yea well ... perhaps you need to think about the evidence, and read your own code more carefully.  (Hint: don't blame the compiler.  99.9% of the time the bug is in your code.  And that increases to 99.99% for if you are only using  standard Java library methods ... and 99.9999% for Java beginners.)  Anyhow, the javadocs >>tell<< you when `next` and `nextLine` will throw that exception .... and they are not lying.

Comment: *"I wouldn't just ask you to do my work for me, that's unfair."* - You would not believe how many people DO do that ....

Comment: All of your help is truly appreciated :)) I'll try to put my head through this issue and fix it, you are absolutely right.

Comment: I fixed the throw error by adding a "myFile.nextLine(); right after line deceleration! 

Now the problem I have is it only finds the first word in the line, as I mentioned before (e.g BOM, Mumbai Airport) When I type BOM, (with the comma) it works fine, but when I type anything else, it doesn't. 

I will try to bang my head against that too, you've already done so much, I'll make sure to credit you. Some hints are appreciated, though, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using the break statement in the if-else block? Try to get rid of the break statement and then execute your code.

```
if(name.equalsIgnoreCase(AirportName))
{
  System.out.println("The name of Airport matches");
}
else
{
 System.out.println("Sorry No Match Found");
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you for such a quick response!

I did get rid of the breaks, it works but to some extent, only the first word works, when I enter any other words in the line, i get 
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:862)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1371)
        at AirportCodes1.main(AirportCodes1.java:37)

Answer (score 0):

Look closely at these two lines.  There's a problem there.  Step through the code in your head pretending you are the `Scanner` class.

```
line = myFile.nextLine();
String name = myFile.next();
```